# Event Confirmation email not being sent

Tags: civicontribute, paypal

I am on version 4.7.19  and whenever someone pays with PayPal the event confirmation email is not beign sent.

The payment is processed, the status is paid, but no email sent.  I have looked at other threads and they say this should be fixed by 4.7.13 but I have a newer version.

On thread mentioned an error on the ConfigAndLog,  and I am getting the FatalErrorDetails

Mar 15 19:13:18 [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array ( [message] => The requested Profile (gid=XXXXX) is disabled OR it is not configured to be used for 'Profile' listings in its Settings OR there is no Profile with that ID OR you do not have permission to access this profile. Please contact the site administrator if you need assistance. [code] => )

Not sure what would be the next step to fixing this. Help Please

I have the IPN return set

Comment: Look at this posting in forum: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22428/the-requested-profile-gid-9-is-disabled-or-not-set-to-be-used?rq=1

Comment: I have been working all day on this issue, It does not seem to me that it is related to the Profile issue.  Really at a wall right now.  WIth regular contributions, emails are sent, it is just with event registration that does not work,  I checked the logs and everything seem ok with the transaction itself. It is just the email is not being triggered to be sent.

Comment: Jennifer, I bet you see the transaction in paypal, does the status change in civi? If not, in paypal there is an option that we can try.

Comment: Yes, the status of everyone that registers for an event and pays through paypal is  is set to Registered and the payment goes through in Paypal.  It is just the email that is not sent.  I must say that most of the transactions are in foregin currency, not sure if that matters.

Comment: What about transactions not through paypal, I can't imagine the foreign currency is a factor, but... did you have any that are not foreign currency?

Comment: Just checking, but in the event setup, is this enabled? Send Confirmation Email?  Yes No

Comment: Yes,  because when you select off line payment the email is sent, it just happens when you go off to paypal

Comment: Ok next question - what CMS are you using? Give me CMS name and version, and version of civi plz.

Comment: Wordpress 4.8.8, CiviCRM 4.7.19  Thank you for your help  I really appreciate it.

Comment: @JenniferBertha did you find a solution to this? Having the same issue, using Drupal 7.65 and CiviCRM 5.10.4

Comment: Nope,  Still sending manual emails after purchase.  If you find solution please share