# The requested Profile is disabled

Tags: wordpress, profile, search

Using 5.17.5 on Wordpress, I've got the dreaded error on a member search form: *"The requested Profile (gid=10) is disabled OR it is not configured to be used for 'Profile' listings in its Settings OR there is no Profile with that ID OR you do not have permission to access this profile"*

The search form works for admins, but not other users or members.

I'm using `[civicrm component="profile" gid="10" mode="search" hijack="0"]` on the search page.

In Admin>Customize Data/Screens>Profiles, the profile exists:

[image]

The profile is active:

[image]

These are the fields:

[image]

Is this a problem with an ACL? Search settings? How do I fix this?

Comment: See if this helps: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/22434/225

Comment: Thanks, I read that a few times; I see that ID 10 is not listed as a Reserved Profile; does it need to be?

Comment: only other suggest is if you have mixed field types eg some are Membership and some are Participant data - but i think that should give a different error. what entities do your fields relate to?

Comment: Entities my fields relate to? You mean the profile fields as shown in the first image above?

Comment: Screenshot added to question.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the relevant profile permissions you have set? Does it work for administrators but not other users?

Comment: @JonG-MegaphoneTech Thanks, it works for admins but no other members. Where do I find profile permissions for ID 10?

Comment: just to swing back to this - yes that screenshot - in the L column it shows in brackets that fields belong to entity = Contact. Profiles can fail if you have eg Entity = Contribution as well as Entity = Participant etc. But i realise this is not helping your problem and Jon has nailed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments, it sounds like you have a permission issue.  It's possible you have an ACL issue, but it's pretty unlikely; you would know if you set up ACLs.

- Go to **Administer menu » Users and Permissions » Permissions (Access Control)**.
- Click the **WordPress Access Control** link.
- Check the permissions: *CiviCRM: profile create* and *CiviCRM: profile view* and ensure they can be used by the role in question.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that was it; the ability to view and search referrals wasn't allowed for the membership level. I still can't seem to allow members to search members, even with that ticked. And it appears that there are other problems; I noticed that the ability to access uploaded files and create/edit profiles has been given to everyone, editors, authors, anonymous users, etc. That seems bad :( .